# How to get all accessor methods for an attribute in a class?

Tags: java

I want to retrieve all accessors for a given attribute in a Java class. I've tried a few things but it is not giving the output I am expecting. For eg:

```
public class demo {
    private String abc;

    public String getAbc() {
        return abc;
    }

    public void setAbc(String abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    public String fetchAbc() {
        return abc;
    }
}
```

Here, the `abc` attribute has two getters, and I want to find there occurences in my project. I tried the following code, which uses the BeanInfo API, but it gives me only one accessor:

```
import java.beans.BeanInfo;
import java.beans.IntrospectionException;
import java.beans.Introspector;
import java.beans.PropertyDescriptor;

public class BeanDemo {

    public void myMethod() throws IntrospectionException {
        BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(demo.class);

        for (PropertyDescriptor property : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            //all attributes of class.
            property.getReadMethod(); // getter
            property.getWriteMethod(); // setter
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell if there is another API that can be used to accomplish this? I can play with reflection but it is not proper way. Thanks.

Comment: really? reflection is not proper way?

Comment: You are using the broader definition of the term 'accessor'. The BeanInfo API relies on certain conventions and defines an accessor as a method that follows a particular naming pattern and signature (aka, getXXX, where XXX is the property in question). To do what you are trying you are going to need some form of static analysis (using tools like PMD).

Comment: @ay89... i need to check return type of every method in that case i guess

Answer (score 1):

First:  [following JavaBean conventions is helpful.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions)  If you have a method that says "retrieve" yet it is an actual getter, it's more confusing to yourself than it is Java - why should there be more than one way to get a field?

Second:  **reflection is your friend.**  You can reflectively pull information about an object with very little pain, and retrieve the results you want.  You should look at [the Reflection Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), as it contains a ton of useful information to get you started.

Here's a minor sample - it will get all of the methods in this class labeled "get".

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Method[] methods = Class.forName("Fake").getMethods();
        for(Method m : methods) {
            if(!m.getDeclaringClass().equals(Object.class) && m.toGenericString().contains("get")) {
                System.out.println(m.toGenericString());
            }
        }
    }
}

class Fake {
    private String objField;
    private int primitiveField;
    private boolean[] arrayField;

    public void setObjField(final String theObjField) {
        objField = theObjField;
    }

    public void setPrimitiveField(final int thePrimitiveField) {
        primitiveField = thePrimitiveField;
    }

    public void setArrayField(final boolean[] theArrayField) {
        arrayField = theArrayField;
    }

    public String getObjField() {
        return objField;
    }

    public int getPrimitiveField() {
        return primitiveField;
    }

    public boolean[] getArrayField() {
        return arrayField;
    }
}
```

The above outputs:

```
public java.lang.String Fake.getObjField()
public int Fake.getPrimitiveField()
public boolean[] Fake.getArrayField()
```

Comment: if objField has one more method say fetchObjField ... in that case it will fail ... i want to find all getters for single attribute..

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to "play with reflection" as it is exactly the proper way.

Start [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), for reflection in general, or [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/index.html), for classes. You may also find [**this reference page**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html) useful.

Here's a hint:

```
Method[] methods = demo.class.getMethods();
for (int i=0; i<methods.length; i++) {
    Method method = methods[i];
    // Take a look at the Method documentation to find out more:
    // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html

    // Or, look at the Method tutorial here:
    // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/method.html
}
```

Check out the [`Class<T>` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and the [`Method` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) at the very least.

Comment: I can play with reflection .... i have no problem i need to check return type name for that ... is that optimal way

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is going only to look at the names and signatures of the methods, it does not look at what they actually do. So can you reliably identify an get/set on that basis?

You can identify all fields: aaa, bbb etc, and then look for all methods whose signatures look like accessors and whose names contain aaa or bbb etc. So you'd find getAaa(), setBbb() and fetchAaa(), and perhaps even bbbFetcher(), but you cannot be sure that any of these really are  what you are looking for. Even were you to scan the source it's tricky: Consider

```
getMagnitude() { return squareRoot( x squared plus y squared) }
```

is that a getter?

Bottom line: pattern matching on names of fields and methods will give you candidates, but you have to devise the matching rules that fit your needs.